# Missing NERDTree Commands

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am relatively new to vim and have an issue with NERDTree that I can't seem to figure out.

I seem to be missing a whole bunch of commands so when I map them to keys, I get the message (for example)

Not an editor command: NERDTreeMapToggleBookmarks

If I run :command I can see all the NERDTree global commands in there (those in section 2.1 of the docs) and these all seem to work but that's it.

I am using NERDTree 4.1.0 which I downloaded fresh from the github repo.
I suspect I may have either missed a step when setting up the plugin or am missing something in my .vimrc but I am at a bit of a loss.

Anyone have any pointers? Like I say, I am new to vim so it could be something really stupid or obvious!! ;)

Many thanks

Comment: I'm running into some similar issues where NERDTree commands are not being found, might be related to some updates I made through Vundle. If I `:PluginUpdate` in Vim, the NERDTree commands work for the Vim session I have open, but if I restart Vim it doesn't work until I run another update...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after updating Vundle to the new interface.
Make sure you have

```
call vundle#begin()
```

and

```
call vundle#end()
```

wrapping your Plugin calls.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem, I have been losing my mind wondering why `:NERDTree` would only run after doing `:PluginInstall`

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into errors like `Not an editor command: NERDTree*`. What broke it for me was changing the line `call vundle#rc()` in my vimrc to `call vundle#begin()` because that's what I saw being used in the [Vundle README](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim#readme). Switching back fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this plugin for a long time. I have checked it and there is only one file in my ./plugins directory and 2 lines in my .vimrc configuration.

- put NERD_tree.vim into .vim/plugins/ directory
- add settings to your .vimrc config file:

```
" NERDTree configuration
let NERDTreeWinSize=35
" map  to toggle NERDTree window
nmap   :NERDTreeToggle
```

And that is all.

Comment: Hi thanks but NERDTree is working and the global commands (such as :NERDTreeToggle) are there.  It is the other commands I am having a problem with.  Thanks anyway tho